# What is the average reader most likely to guess that “If they don’t have A or both B and C” was exactly intended to mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, negation, logic, readability

There is a sentence saying "If they don't have A or both B and C,"

I interpret it means "If they have no A or if they have neither B or C". Am I correct?

The condition seems to me that having only B or C alone is not enough, but having A alone is OK and having both B and C is OK too even if A is missing. I am not sure.

Comment: Why should "average readers" be able to figure out what an ambiguous assertion means?

Comment: I would AND the B and C in your interpretation.

Comment: I don’t see how your first interpretation could be possible. Only possible interpretation to me is that the condition is that they must have either A or they must have both B and C. Having only one of B or C alone would not be enough, so “if they have no A or if they have neither B [n]or C” is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you're correct, but your re-statement of the condition is even more obscure.

The verb is only mentioned once, so it must apply to both conditions. There are two conditions, because there is an *or* and the *and* is part of "both B and C" — the *both* links B and C together.

The statement can't actually be reduced any more, but let's say it's

> If they don't have A or both B and C, then X.

- If they don't have A, then X
- If they don't have both B and C, then X

The way to prevent X is to have *either* A *or* both B and C together. A real-world example is needing identification: you can get a discount with *either* a photocard driving licence (showing name, address and photo) *or both* a passport (name and photo) and a utility bill (name and address).

It would certainly be easier to say "X **unless** they have A or both B and C."

Comment: That's the way I read it, for example, "If they don't have any matches, or both a flint and a steel, they won't be able to make a fire."

Comment: WeatherVane -- Nice use of a real-world example!

Comment: @user8356 real olde-world perhaps ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. I added a slightly more modern example.

Answer (score 3):

Above-average reader parses it this way.

I can have thing A.
I can have both things B and C.
I could actually have all 3 things.

Any of those would meet the condition. Having only thing B without thing C does not meet the condition.

If this was written as a pseudo-code query for a database:

(If A) OR (If B AND C), then proceed...